# Horizontal Scrollbar missing

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I want horizontal scrollbar to be displayed. I have used `overflow-x:scroll;` but I don't see any horizontal scroll bar. Please help.

```
<div class="abc">
  <p>This is overflow-x scroll. This is overflow-x scroll. This is overflow-x scroll.</p>
</div>
.abc{
  overflow-x:scroll;
  width:1000px;
}
```

My code here is [here](http://jsbin.com/hekosiwito/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Please add the code to the question. You can keep the jsbin in the question as well. The reason to add the code in a code block is in case the jsbin link breaks in the future, the question could still help a future user.

Comment: this is a volunteer site. Do not call people names and do not expect help. They vote based on the quality of the question. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the your code in jsbin, try this :

```
.abc{
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can keep one of the these as required 'auto' or 'scroll'.
There are many other Property Values, check here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your example you should set the white-space value to nowrap in your inner div.

take a look at the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <title>JS Bin</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="a">
       <div class="scrollviewer">
           <p class="datacontainer">This is overflow-x scroll. This is overflow-x scroll. 
           <br/>
           This is overflow-x scroll.This is overflow-x scroll.This is overflow-x scroll.This is overflow-x scroll.This is overflow-x scroll.This is overflow-x scroll.This is overflow-x scroll.This is overflow-x scroll.</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

and the css:

```
.scrollviewer{
   overflow-x: scroll;
   width:100%;
}
.datacontainer{
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```